# Apple Script does not open Excel 2011 on MAC

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

Can somebody please explain what is wrong in the below applescript:

```
tell the application id "com.microsoft.Excel"
set excel to open workbook workbook file name "Users:Tom:Desktop:ID_Creation.xlsx"
end tell
```

I have Office2011 installed. 
It gives the following error:

```
/usr/bin/osascript test.scpt 
test.scpt:59:137: execution error: Microsoft Excel got an error: Can’t continue open workbook. (-1708)
```

I even tried with launch and activate command  but in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh I see your problem: You didn't specify the drive name. So, instead, you should do

```
set excel to "<your_drive_name>:Users:Tom:Desktop:ID_Creation.xlsx"
```

Comment: Thanks. This works.But without the drive name this was working in Office2008. Is there a difference in both these versions.

Comment: @Subrat I think in Office2008 the drive name was supplied automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to work with disks and long paths if your file is on your Desktop or in your Home folder somewhere. There are built-in shortcuts that tell you the path to various important folders. For example, “the path to the desktop folder,” “the path to the home folder,” “the path to the documents folder,” “the path to the downloads folder.” They all act as an alias to those folders on your system, including automatically specifying the correct name of the startup disk, so that even if you change it later, your scripts will still work. If you want the path to your desktop folder as text instead of an alias — for example, to build a file path — then just ask for “the path to the desktop folder as text.”

I don’t use Excel, but here is an example using Finder:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFilePath to (the path to desktop folder as text) & "ID_Creation.xlsx"
    open file theFilePath
end tell
```

… which should work to open that file in Excel on your computer, assuming that Excel is the default application for opening files with that file extension.

Here is your script rewritten using this technique, which should work on your computer, assuming that the rest of your script was correct — as I said, I don’t use Excel, so I can’t test this:

```
tell the application id "com.microsoft.Excel"
    set theFilePath to (the path to desktop folder as text) & "ID_Creation.xlsx"
    set excel to open workbook workbook file name theFilePath
end tell
```

… and here is your script cleaned up a bit, to address Excel in the conventional way, and to use a variable for your opened workbook that is not exactly the same as Excel’s name, since that may be confusing at some point later.

```
tell application "Excel"
    set theFilePath to (the path to desktop folder as text) & "ID_Creation.xlsx"
    set theExcelWorkbook to open workbook workbook file name theFilePath
end tell
```